# Align controls to a Column on DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a peculiar requirement where i have to align couple of controls to a column on the `DataGrid`. The `DataGrid`has 13 columns and I need the controls aligning to the 6th column. These controls are outside of the `DataGrid`. So even when a user resizes the right border of the column (one of the columns on the `DataGrid`) the controls need to track that and move along with that. Basically, the controls need to align to the column border of the `DataGrid`. This column could be any one of the columns on the `DataGrid`.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution to this tricky problem.

Thanks again for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can subscribe to the column resize event, and then sum up the `ActualWidth` of columns 1-5.

Comment: Thanks Leonid, Is there a way to subscribe to the column resize event?? I found a columnreordering and a column reordering event did not find one specific to column resizing.